# DotNetOpenAuth and Google OpenId Params

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I am still reading on using dotnetopenauth and google openid. In the google docs they mention some parameters that need to be passed like:

"openid.ns", "openid.claimed_id", "openid.identity", "openid.ax.type.email" etc ...

Does DotNetOpenAuth send all those params on its own seamlessly?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm trying to figure out how to set "openid.return_to" using dotnetopenauth? Any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth sets all the OpenID standard parameters automatically, including `openid.return_to`.  If you want to customize `openid.realm` or `openid.return_to`, you can pass values for them as parameters to `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest`.  Other parameters you can customize or add by setting properties or calling methods on the `IAuthenticationRequest` that is returned by `CreateRequest` before you call `RedirectToProvider`.

In particular, you can specify the `openid.ax.type.email` parameter by adding a `FetchRequest` extension to the outgoing request with email included as a required attribute.  Then in the response check for the `FetchResponse` extension.

Comment: What will DNOA use as `openid.return_to` by default?

Comment: The current page of your web site.